# Handling multiple forms with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to handle multiple forms with ajax.  Suppose I have #formA, and #formB.  And in the submitForm() function, I have the following:

```
function submitForm() {
  var currentForm = $(this);
  if (currentForm == "#formA") {
   //do this
  }
  else if (currentForm == "#formB"){
   //do that
  } 
}
```

However this approach is not working. What is the best way to deal with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try modifying your code:

```
function submitForm() {
  var currentForm = $(this);
  if (currentForm.attr("id") == "formA") {
   //do this
  }
  else if (currentForm.attr("id") == "formB") {
   //do that
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the code which you have written will not work, because you are `trying to compare a jquery object with a string`.

you have to use `attr` method of jquery to fetch the id of form and then compare it...something like this-

```
function submitForm() {
  var currentForm = $(this);
  if (currentForm.attr("id") == "formA") {
   //do this
  }
  else if (currentForm.attr("id") == "formB") {
   //do that
  } 
}
```